# HR rescheduling interview call recurrently (like an infinite loop)

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I am a final year student doing Masters and had applied for a job. An HR contacted me after a month and scheduled an interview call but kept on rescheduling it at the last moment twice a week for two weeks (every time saying something urgent came up in an unplanned way), after which I sent a declination.

What can be the reason or meaning of repeatedly booking time for interview (the calendar request shows only me and the HR herself) just to keep rescheduling it? And is it unprofessional if I ask her not to contact me again if she intends to waste time this way?

Following are the detailed sequence of events happened.

Day 1 : I got a missed call at 5 pm, and a mail saying 'I am HR of XYZ company, trying to reach you in regard of your job application. Please call me back during my working hours  9 am - 5 pm.'

Day 2 : I call her at 4:45 pm and found out she had already left office, and will call back later today/tomorrow.

Day 3 : I wait. Send a mail at 4 pm,  before entering into a class, specifying my free times for next 3 days.

Day 4 : The HR called. I told her that my course will be over after 7 months from now, she enquires if I am sitting for a campus interview and if I have already got one. She says I should keep her informed about the status of my campus interviews and if I want to get in touch with her after 3-4 months. As I am really interested in the area this company works on, I told her so. She enquired about my free mornings and scheduled a call at 11:30 am for a technical interview and said it is an exploratory call.

Day 5 : At 9:15am a call from her, saying no interview today due to unavailability of interviewer's time, rescheduled to Thursday 11:30 am.

Day 6: At 11:15, a rescheduling mail, with new time as Tuesday 11:30 am next week. This time no call and no excuse given.

Day 7: At 11:30 am, a rescheduling mail, with new time as Thursday 11:30 am, with a note like "I am extremely sorry to reschedule your interview again, some urgent meeting came up." etc.

Day 8 : Waiting alone in the interview link at 11:30 am. Another rescheduling mail at 11:32 am, with a sorry note that something urgent came up.

I decline the meeting request with a note "Hello Mam, I was waiting at the hangout call. As it seems like you are busy now, I would request to connect after 3-4 months, as you were suggesting earlier. My exams are also nearby, I can't afford to wait for the interview and then get a reschedule call at all my free days, as I need to utilize them for advancing my studies"

On next Monday I get a mail like this "Sorry for the last-minute reschedules - we couldn't make it due to a medical emergency and I was unable to get in touch with you to inform you of the same.
I'll go ahead and put this on hold for a few months as discussed.
All the best for your exams!"

I am tempted to write a reply like this.
"Dear mam, hope you get well soon. Please contact me after 3-4 months, only if you are serious about taking my interview and recruiting me. I never saw any interviewer's time booked for these series of rescheduled meetings, and I believe you yourself was not intending to take my technical interview in machine learning. Requesting you not to waste my time anymore if you do not really intend to recruit me."
Will it be unprofessional to reply like this, and it is better to just not reply anything?

Comment: Two points: One: do you want to work for a shambles like this? Two: how can we know their reason…

Comment: If this was a technical interview, it likely wasn't the HR woman actually doing the interview.  She is probably just coordinating the schedule with the actual interviewer, whose schedule she doesn't control.  Given the current issues with COVID and related staffing concerns, you may want to be more tolerant.

Comment: _"the calendar request shows only me and the HR herself"_ That doesn't mean they are the one doing the actual interview. Some companies will (at least initially) shield other employees from direct contact with the interviewee, which means that the calendar invite to you does not include actual interviewers.

Comment: If you are ready to give up on them, truly honest feedback serves no purpose. Make it polite and move on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tldr: Professional means to focus on your goals & commitments and leave your emotions and fragile ego out of it.**

> Will it be unprofessional to reply like this,

Yes, very much so. It will guarantee that you will not get the job and you will come across as overly sensitive and spoiled.

> is better to just not reply anything?

No. It's most effective to send a friendly thank you e-mail like **"thanks for reaching out, I'd be happy to connect in a few months and I'm also available in between if that helps. Sorry about your medical emergency, I hope everyone is well ."**

So let's look at what happened here.

1. You want an exploratory chat with a company you are interested in and you actually got a foot in the door. Great !
2. You got contacted by an HR staffer. They have probably 25 other candidates they are working on and your potential employment is still 7 months out. That means you are on the BOTTOM of their priority list. Keep in mind that this is probably a first line staffer, who often are very junior and still learning the ropes as well.
3. The staffer tries a few times to arrange an interview but it doesn't work out and communication around it is suboptimal. While inconvenient, this actual fairly normal. You are a low priority hire and urgent things do indeed come up on a daily basis. Could also be bad luck, incompetence, internal miscommunication, actual medical emergencies. Who knows.

You have a couple of choices here

1. Throw a hissy fit and complain.
2. Become passive-aggressive and go to radio silence
3. Remain friendly and co-operative

I can't think of a scenario where #3 isn't the most effective option. It takes 5 minutes to write and you are still in the running. If you don't want the job anymore you can still say no later at the next step.

With the other two options you just come across as immature and unprofessional. No one wants to hire that.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting it, as it looks like the best answer to me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it would be unprofessional to end this entire "almost, but not quite" process with the phrase "not waste my time."

To start with, being professional is basically "making it easy to get work done."  Were you professional when you basically gave them one hour a week to be interviewed, at a time that crosses both 1/2 of the hour before lunch and 1/2 of lunch?

Also, it doesn't matter how many times you've communicated with them; because, it's more professional to communicate in ways that reduce the number of required communications.

So, before you worry about their professionalism, focus on what you can control.  First decide if you want the job, and then decide what you want to do.

If you want the job, find three options to meet.  Those options should be spread across at least two days, and should not all be in the same hour.  Ideally you'd provide a morning and a "just after lunch" option; because those are easier for working people to commit to.  "Just before you leave work" options are not great options, as by then one's probably tied up with the events of the day.  Let them know if they can't make any of the options, they should give you three times to meet and you'll see if you can accommodate them.

If you don't want the job, then tell them it's just not the right time for you yet.  You can't make them wait four months, their projects might not be able to wait that long; by then they might have already hired all the personnel they need.

To quote Winston Churchill, "Diplomacy is the art of telling people to go to hell in such a way that they ask for directions."  Don't mess it up by saying they wasted your time, instead say what you really mean, "you don't want to interview for a job at this moment."

Saying they are wasting your time is judging them, which is entirely unnecessary and professionally dangerous.  You might come off on the wrong side of public opinion, as who knows, maybe there was a car accident, emergency at their child's school, or some other item you'd normally forgive that got in the way of your phone call.  I'd be very careful to avoid such judgements on so little information.

Comment: It was HR that scheduled 11.30 as the time for the call, based on free mornings.

Comment: @SolarMike And all the times are Thursday, and all the times are 11:30AM, based on the free times presented by the poster.  There seems to be a lack of variety in meeting times, perhaps due to not enough options in "free times" being presented to them.

Comment: Well one was Tuesday - did you miss that?

Comment: @SolarMike Probably because Tuesday and Thursday seem similar to me; but, you're right, there are two days involved.  Was there some point of my advice you didn't agree with?  I'd like to alter the question to address your concerns, if you think the advice is bad.

Comment: You blamed the OP in paragraph 2 and the time was chosen by HR based on the free mornings offered by OP. I find Tuesday very different to Thursday - Thursday one is looking forward to the weekend.

Comment: Yes, I only gave the days of the week, I am free. The time was set by HR.